# Common subview between two views hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, sorting, uiview

I have two views V1 and V2 which have n and m subviews respectively. Among the m and n subviews there is a view 'p' which is common.

I am trying to find out this common view 'p' among m and n subviews. Obviously the brute force approach of O(m*n) works fine to get the common view p. But I would like to know if there is a better efficient algorithm that I can use to get that one unique common view which is present in both V1 and V2.

V1 = {B, K, L, P, O, B, C, A, Q, R}
V2 = {A, X, W, S, T, K, O};

Running brute-force gives me O as the answer in O(m*n). Here the views O and O have same class.
As pointed out in the comments, I am NOT looking for views which have same frame.

Any efficient way to do this?

After some thoughts and also @CrimsonChris answer's, I have the below solution

```
- (void)commonView:(UIView *)a1 with:(UIView *)a2 {

    NSMutableSet *s = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithCapacity:[[a1 subviews] count]];
    for (UIView *a1SubViews in [a1 subviews]) {
        [s addObject:[a1SubViews class]];
    }

    for (UIView *a2SubView in [a2 subviews]) {
        if ([s containsObject:[a2SubView class]]) {
            NSLog(@"#Boom, I found the common view %@", a2SubView);
            return;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"NO common subview");
    return;
}
```

But this uses O(n) space, can we optimize it more further?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a view can only have one superview. What are you really asking, how to do tree traversal?

Comment: I want to know if I can find a view from V1 (lets say at position ith index) matching a view from V2 at jth index. Is that possible in a better algorithmic complexity?

Comment: So you're not REALLY looking for a common view. Just a view that has the same coordinates?

Comment: Let's assume same class, coz if I go with co-ordinates then let's say B view with frame(0,0,120,40) and X view with frame(0,0,120,40) will be same but the class of B (which is B) and class of X(which is X) is not same.

Comment: You should really define what you mean by "common" in your question. There is no way for two views to share the EXACT SAME view in their subviews.

Comment: I would recommend whatever approach gives you the cleanest code. iOS is not a platform where you will have a large number of nested views. What kind of program needs to worry about view traversal performance?

Comment: It was a random question asked and I was stuck on this question for a while to solve it. But I believe there should be one. This is not a app specific but just a nerd food :-P

Comment: Pretty sure that solution won't work. You won't find any views that have pointer equality.

Comment: This isn't really an iOS question at its heart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a hash table out of the subviews with each subview's class name as the key.

That's O(n) performance but also O(n) in size.

Comment: hmm yeah, any space optimization. I will accept your answer in few days. I am looking to do it most optimally.

Comment: Sorting is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with O(1) space and O(max(m , n) log m ) time (with m <= n).

If we have two array `int[]a and b` with n and m elements:

- First, we can sort array b -> time complexity is O(mlogm)
- For each element of array a -> use **binary search** to search for this element in array b -> time complexity is O(nlogm)

So at the end, we have a total time complexity is  O(max(m , n) log m ) with space is O(1) if you use in-place sorting algorithm (for example: merge - sort).

We can replace `int[] a and b` with any Object array, as long as these Object are **comparable**. (Using hash code is also an option).